# how do I use nodes in C?

Tags: c, xcode, struct, nodes

(This is about finding what's wrong with my program) I am quite new to programming and I am currently learning how to use structures and nodes in C and I made this simple program that is supposed to read and register the data of a movie, but I don't know what am I doing wrong as my compiler keeps showing this:
•Calling 'fillMovieData' with incomplete return type 'struct node' *(at line 17)*
•incomplete result result type 'struct node' in function definition *(at line 22)*
•returning 'struct cinema' from a structure with incompatible result type  'struct node' *(at line 32)*

do you know how can I fix this errors?, I'll appreciate all the feedback I can get!
The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct cinema{
    char *name;
    char *genre;
    short year;
    short numDirectors;
    char *directors[10];
};
void printMovieData(struct cinema);
struct node fillMovieData(char *, char *, short , short , char *[10]);

int main(){
    char *directors[10];
    directors[0] = "Lana Wachowski";
    directors[1] = "Andy Wachowski";
    struct cinema matrix = fillMovieData("The matrix", "Fiction", 1999, 2, directors); // this is line 17
    printMovieData(matrix);
    return 0;
}

struct node fillMovieData(char *name, char *genre, short year,short numDirectors, char *directors[10]){ //this is line 22
    struct cinema movie;
    movie.name = name;
    movie.genre = genre;
    movie.year = year;
    movie.numDirectors = numDirectors;
    int cont = 0;
    for ( ; cont < movie.numDirectors ; cont++){
        movie.directors[cont] = directors[cont];
    }
    return movie; //this is line 32
}

void printMovieData(struct cinema movie){
    printf("MOVIE: %s\n", movie.name);
    printf("GENRE: %s\n", movie.genre);
    printf("YEAR: %d\n", movie.year);
    printf("DIRECTOR(S):\n");
    int cont = 0;
    for ( ; cont < movie.numDirectors ; cont++){
        printf("%s\n", movie.directors[cont]);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you define node structure? I cant see its definition also its declaration

Comment: could you go into more detail with that?, I have searched In some websites and I have seen that I have to use typedef for that, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fillMovieData` function is returning the value of `movie`, which has type `struct cinema`.  Also, you don’t have a definition for type `struct node` like you do for `struct cinema`.

It’s clear to me that you meant to declare `fillMovieData` as

```
struct cinema fillMovieData( ... ) { ... }
```

.

Comment: thanks a lot for taking some of your time on helping and explaining the mistake!
this will be pretty useful for the next programs I'll make

Answer (score 0):

in line 17:
you define a movie data type `struct cinema matrix` but the function you use

```c
fillMovieData("The matrix", "Fiction", 1999, 2, directors);
```

returns a node data type
also line 22 and 32 try to say that you use different data type for returning value of **fillMovieData** function

```c
struct node fillMovieData(char *, char *, short , short , char *[10]);
```

returns type of `struct node` but in definition you return `movie` which is type of `struct cinema` data type.

Comment: BIG THANKS! you helped me a lot in understanding the logic behind my errors and I was actually interpreting an answer from your explanation, I appreciate a lot your help